# Imagemagick tiff installed and working but php Imagick extension supports no tiff

Tags: php, path, imagemagick, tiff, imagick

I'm running xampp on macOS (10.12.6) and installed Imagemagick (ImageMagick 7.0.7-3 Q16 x86_64 2017-09-19 ).

With the installed php Imagick extension, I can convert in php images from jpeg to png without problems.

But when I want to convert from tiff to png/jpeg, it doesnt work with the Imagick extension. But it works in terminal and the Imagemagick tiff DELEGATE is supported.

When I look at phpinfo(), there's no tiff support listed.

the PHP error is:

> Uncaught ImagickException: unable to load module
>   '/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.7-3/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16HDRI/coders/tiff.la':
>   file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1270

Is the problem the double-backslash in the path?

When I navigate in the finder to the path with doubleback-backslash removed, there is the correct file.

Comment: You can execute the command that works on command line in PHP exec() function.

Comment: That would work but the file-data is stored in a var and not in a tiff-file. and saving the file is no option... so i need to use readImageBlob()... And i don't think a can use exec() on my hosted server.

Comment: Then you are stuck, apparently...

Comment: yes i tested a lot but nothing works... i don't know why my php imagick doesn't show tiff as supported format.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution among the answers to [issue #3919 for Homebrew on GitHub](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/3919).

Try recompiling php-imagick71 and imagemagick one or several times in different order.

```
brew reinstall -s php-imagick71
brew reinstall -s imagemagick
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but unfortunately that's not the solution... changes nothing, there is still the problem.